# Three.js skinned animation mesh disappears when material skinning is true

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've exported an animated model from Blender which doesn't seem to have any issue instantiating. I'm able to create the `THREE.Animation` and model, but I was finding there was no animation. I realized I needed to set `skinning` true on each material, but when I do that the entire mesh goes missing.

Below is my (quick and messy) code trying to get everything to work.

```
function loadModel() {
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        loader.load('assets/models/Robot.js', function(geom, mat) {
            _mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
            _scene.add(_mesh);

            geom.computeBoundingBox();

            ensureLoop(geom.animation);
            THREE.AnimationHandler.add(geom.animation);

            for (var i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
                var m = mat[i];
                //m.skinning = true; <-- Uncommenting this makes the model disappear
                //m.morphTargets = true; <-- This causes all sorts of WebGL warnings

                m.wrapAround = true;
            }

            var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geom, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mat));
            mesh.scale.set(400, 400, 400);
            mesh.position.set(0, -200, 0);
            mesh.rotation.set(Utils.toRadians(-90), 0, 0);
            _mesh.add(mesh);
            _robot = mesh;
            Render.startRender(loop);

            var animation = new THREE.Animation(mesh, geom.animation.name);
            animation.JITCompile = false;
            animation.interpolationType = THREE.AnimationHandler.LINEAR;
            animation.play();

        });
    }
```

I believe I'm updating the AnimationHandler correctly in my loop

```
function loop() {
    _mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

    var delta = 0.75 * _clock.getDelta();
    THREE.AnimationHandler.update(delta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the section **metadata** of the exported JSON file the number of **morphTargets** and **bones** are both greater than 0?

I think that you followed the example here:

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_skinning_morph

in which the animated model uses Morph Target and Skeletal Animation (see Wikipedia for the theoretical concepts).

If the animated model uses only Skeletal Animation as in this example http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_animation_skinning_tf2.html

you have to instantiate a **THREE.SkinnedMesh** Object and then set only the **m.skinning** property to **true**.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem just now. What worked for me was to remake the model with applied scale and have keyframes for LocRotScale, not just location.

Answer (score 0):

lately, I've encoutered a similar issue of mesh disapearing while exporting blender skinning animation to json. It turned out, the mesh I was using had double vertex (one vertice hidding another). All looks good While creating the vertex groups and the animations in blender, but when I imported the mesh via three.js, it kept disapearing as soon as the animation started. In other words, If 1 vertice from your mesh is omitted from  the vertex groups, you will experience this disapearing behavior. To prevent this issue, I now use the "remove doubles" function from blender to validate the mesh integrity before exporting it to json. You might have encountered the same issue and redoing your mesh work fix it... Anyways, the question is pretty old, but the topic is still valid as of today, so I hope this fresh info will help someone out there...

Peace INF1